# Expressing a number field as a composite of extensions ramified at one place

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, nt.number-theory

If $K$ is a number field, is it always possible to find a finite extension $L/K$ such that $L$ is the composite of fields $L_1,\ldots, L_n$, with the property that at most one prime ramifies in $L_i/\mathbb{Q}$? Equivalently, is the composite of all extensions ramified at $\leq 1$ place all of $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$?

The first question has an affirmative answer when $K$ is abelian, but for the general case, the equivalent second question sounds too strong to be true. Any ideas?

Comment: As I read it, the first question is equivalent to find one finite extension $L/K$ ramified at most at one place. And I don't see why this is equivalent to the second question.

Comment: Sorry about that; edited for clarity.

Comment: I'm still a little confused.  For example, your first question could be answered affirmatively if you could find, say, a quadratic extension of K ramified at a single prime.  This seems unlikely to imply your second question...

Comment: Cam, $K$ could be heavily ramified, while the $L_i$ are required to be ramified at at most one place *over $\mathbb{Q}$*.

Comment: I would try proving that the answer is no for the field K generated by a cube root of 2.

Comment: I agree with Franz, the field K generated by the cube root of 2 looks like a good starting point, but it might be tricky to prove that the answer is no for such fields. E.g., Lassina Dembele constructs a non-solvable Galois extension F_2/Q ramified only at 2 with Galois group 2.SL(2,F_8)^2, and it might account for the correct tame ramification at 2 (at least its degree is a multiple of 3). So K might well be contained in the compositum of F_2 and some non-solvable F_3/Q ramified only at 3. These exist as well by Dembele- Greenberg-Voight, so it looks really hard... Nice question!

Comment: Since the Galois closure of an extension ramified at a single prime has the same property, we may assume that the $L_i$ are normal with Galois groups $G_i$. Their direct product must have a quotient isomorphic to $S_3$, the Galois group of the normal closure of $Q(2^{1/3})$. Can we extract information on the structure of the $G_i$ from that?

Comment: Dear Franz: Some of the $L_i$'s may be ramified over the same rational prime, so this collection of fields is not necessarily mutually linearly disjoint over $\mathbf{Q}$ (i.e., the tensor product of the $L_i$'s may not be a field). So their composite field has Galois group that is merely contained in the direct product, and hence the Galois group of the Galois closure of $K$ over $\mathbf{Q}$ may not be (naturally) a quotient of the direct product of the Galois groups of the $L_i$'s over $\mathbf{Q}$. 

Comment: @BCnrd: if L_1 and L_2 are ramified at the same prime, replace them by their compositum. 

Comment: Dear Franz: Ah, whoops, that was dumb of me. So the mystery of the structure of the $G_i$'s seems even worse than I was imagining. 

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I believe the answer is `No', and Franz Lemmermeyer's example $K=Q(2^{1/3})$ and his strategy of the proof do the trick.

Suppose this particular $K$ is contained in the compositum $F$ of $L_i$, with every $L_i$ ramified at only one prime. Assume each $L_i$ is Galois over $Q$ (otherwise replace it by its Galois closure) and that no two $L_i$ ramify at the same prime $p$ (otherwise replace this pair by their compositum). The $L_i$ are then linearly disjoint over $Q$, since their pairwise intersections would have to be unramified at all primes. So $G=Gal(F/Q)$ is the direct product of $Gal(L_i/Q)$'s.

Now the group $G$ has a 2-dimensional irreducible representation $\rho$, the one that factors through the Galois closure of $K/Q$ (an $S_3$-extension of $Q$). As $G$ is the direct product of groups, we can write $\rho=\rho_1\otimes...\otimes\rho_n$ uniquely, with $\rho_i$ irreducible representations of $Gal(L_i/Q)$. Moreover, $\rho$ is self-dual, so all the $\rho_i$ are self-dual as well. Of these $\rho_i$ one must be 2-dimensional and the others are 1-dimensional. Because 1-dimensional self-dual characters have order 2, this shows that at all primes $p$ except at most one (the one corresponding to the 2-dimensional $\rho_i$) inertia $I_p$ acts on $\rho$ through a quotient of order 2. But $I_2$ and $I_3$ act through quotients of order 3 and 6 respectively, contradiction!

Comment: Dear Tim: Very nice. A tiny correction is that pairwise triviality of intersections does not quite suffice to justify the required linear disjointness in general (but we have more ramification information, and so have disjointness of each $L_i$ against the compositum of the others, say also proceeding by induction on the number of $L_i$ or whatever; of course, you had all of this in mind so as to not really need to worry about it). For example, in a biquadratic field the 3 quadratic subfields have pairwise trivial intersections but the triple is not a linearly disjoint collection. 

Comment: You're right of course, I did not put this correctly! Also, as my brother has pointed out, all this representation theory nonsense can be avoided: the group $G=G_1*...*G_n$ acts on three points (the embeddings of $K$ into $C$), and its very difficult to have pairwise commuting groups to act on 3 points. As one of them, corresponding to $p=3$, is the whole of $S_3$, all the others must act trivially, so $K$ cannot be ramified at any other prime.

Comment: @Tim: Nice answer (both of them)! That second one is quite slick.